# Printing a variable in C that was not assigned a value

Tags: c, variables, memory-address

I put this code into eclipse and run it

```
main()
{
  int *p, *q, *r;
  int a = 10, b = 25;
  int c[4] = {6,12,18,24};

  p = c;

  printf("p = %d\n" ,p);
}
```

the output I get is
p = 2358752

what is this number supposed to represent? Is it the address of the variable?

If what i'm saying above is true would my answer to the following question be correct?

so lets say the following are stored at the following locations

```
address      variables

5000         p

5004         q

5008         r

500C         a

5010         b

5014        c[0]

5018        c[1]

501C        c[2]

5020        c[3]
```

so would  would the line

```
p = c;
```

be 5014?

Comment: Answers to the questions: Yes, Yes.

Comment: It is undefined behaviour to print a pointer using `%d`.  What is likely to happen is that the memory containing the pointer value is interpreted as if it contained an int.  If your system uses flat memory model and non-trapping ints and other common assumptions, and sizeof(int*) == sizeof(int) then you would probably get the address displayed properly. But you shoudl use `*p` and cast to `void *` to be reliable.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Did you mean 'you should use `%p` and cast to `void *`'?  I would agree with that analysis.  And it is worth noting that on most 64-bit systems, `sizeof(int) != sizeof(int *)`, so using `%d` to print addresses is inherently a portability liability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `p` is the address of `c`, which is the same as the address of `c[0]`. And yes, in your second example, `p` would be equal to 5014.

Comment: I have another question why is it that p=c gives the address of c[0]? Is it because it is the first element of the array?

Comment: Yes, absolutely ! In C, there is no difference between the memory location of an array and the memory location of its first element.

Answer (score 2):

```
int *p,
```

The above statement defines `p` to be a pointer to an integer. 
In the below statement, `c` is implicitly converted to a pointer to the first element of the array `a`.

```
p = c;
// equivalent to
p = &c[0];
```

Therefore, `p` contains the address of the first element of the array. Also, the conversion specifier to print an address is `%p`.

```
printf("p = %p\n", (void *)p);
// prints the same address
printf("c = %p\n", (void *)c);
```